# What is the best way to validate multiple XML files against a XSD?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I am working on a project that requires the validation of many XML files against their XSD, the trouble I am having is that many of the **XSD files depend on others XSDs**, making the usual validation kind of troublesome, is there an elegant way to resolve this issue?

*I would prefer if possible to work with those files in memory, the files are not in a concise directory structure that conforms with their importation paths.*

*Just to note I am working with the Java language.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming here that you work with JAXP, so that you can `setSchema()` on either `SAXParserFactory` or `DocumentBuilderFactory.

One solution I was part of, was to read all XSD sources into an aggregated `Schema` object using `SchemaFactory.newSchema(Source[] schemas)`. This aggregated Schema was then able to validate any XML document that referenced any "top" schema; all `imported` schemas had to be part of the aggregated schema. As I remember it, it was necessary to order the Source array by dependency, so that if Schema A imported Schema B, Schema B had to occur befor Schema A in the array.

Also, as I recall, `<include>` didn't work very well with this mechanism.

Another solution would be to set an `LSResourceResolver` on the ShemaFactory. You would have to implement your own `LSResourceresolver` that serves byte- or character streams based on the input to the resolver. I haven't personally used or researched this solution.

The first solution has of course the benefit that schema parsing and processing can be done once and reused for all validations that follows; something that will probably be difficult to achieve with the second option.

Another thing to keep in mind (depending on your context): It is a good design choice to control the whole "resolving" process (i.e. control how the parsers get access to external resources), from a performance as well as a security perspective.